# Masterthesis - optimization/design a board - help required

Tags: pcb-design, layout

For my master thesis I have to optimize a already build board that was only quick made on a previous master thesis. The Board itself is not that complex and works as an actuator controller via a microcontroller (ESP32). Overall my knowledge for design is low-decent, but that's the thing I like as I learn something new everyday. But I am scared to get lost on the way and cant even finishes the basic requirements till the deadline arrives.
Previous Version:
Uses an external ESP32 via a pin header to control around 16~ NMOS who control the actuators(12/24V, 10-500mA different kind of actuators) also some sensor are controlled aswell. The ESP32 get's it data via WLAN over MQTT/JSON Data.

As for the optimization I need to implement Ethernet (I will use an LAN8720A and the internal MAC from the ESP32 because of stability and speed). A stable power regulation with Vin in range of 12-24V and Vout of 12V with enough Amps for all the actuators(Around 8A max.)
Because the ESP32 has to few pins for everything I need, I use I2C MCP23008 expanders to control the logic level MOSFET. 2 x 8 allows me to control all my 16 FETs with enough current for switching (Maybe even a level shifter to 5V for a bit more switching power?)

Overall, as you can see in all of my previous posts I already asked ALOT and will probly. Do even more and I am so thankful for every help I get here.

Over a month and a half are now over and I have 5 month overall. So not that much left as I still need to order the PCB which takes a few weeks, code the ESP32 and need to write the text aswell.

Now my questions:
What is the best way to do further? What is the typical way if someone designs or optimizes an already existing layout? I know I should have asked this probly. At the beginning but I feel like only now I have the complete picture of my task.
I am already at the part of designing the layout. ( we try to use through-hole because it's simpler but some things can't be done there)
What would be my next step? I thought about making a small prototype now with only the important stuff to work on the coding and maybe check if the overall master layout needs to be done better...

If you could guide me, I would be really thankful.

EDIT:
Maybe the text was misguiding as english is not my native language.
I don't want a someone to design it for me. That is my task.
I would just like to have some tips and guidance for what are common steps, where do mistakes happen a lot and what should I watch when I am designing. Obsiously I will still do mistakes as that are what thesises are about and how to solve them but I don't want to run into a "dead-end" !

Greetings.

PS: If you need more information or anything else just ask.

Comment: You want us to design it for you? That is how it appears. Your education is supposed to give you the knowlege to understand and solve a given problem. You’ve not demonstrated this.

Comment: No I def. not want you to design it for me. I would like to know what are common steps to design a PCB and where are traps I can avoid and tips I can use from people with way more experience than me.

Comment: So what is your question? Pretend SO is a magic genie - you can ask three questions, so make them good.

Comment: Your question and thesis should look more like a datasheet for a product with specifications, theory of Operation, Design Validation Test results, discussion of  challenges, interference, errors and opportunities. Otherwise it looks very  "Mickey Mouse" or "academic" and not very professional.  I realize it is hard to identify specs you do not know exist and I was there too at one time.  That's why you start reading professional design with Theory of Operation learn, how to write a spec like a datasheet just like the components as a model.  H-bridge MOSFET ESC controllers is not something new.

Comment: @DanielDo - Hi, With respect for what you are trying to do, this question as asked is just too broad (too many different parts to the question). I would not even be trying to ask those questions *now*, given the timescale that you describe. In your place I would be doing more project planning, and less (or zero) PCB designing, to ensure that you complete *something* usable by the deadline. Only after you have that plan, decide what time is available for the different parts of the project. Using chat here may be a better way for you to discuss broad topics. Do you want me to create a chat room?

Comment: I understand. The answer from blub already provide some guidance. I didnt know there is a chat here. I would appreciate if you could open a chat room for me. Thanks !

Comment: @DanielDo - There is an "always open" general chat room for the Electronics site [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering), where you can ask questions. Advantage of using that one = more people will visit there, just to see what is happening, so more people will see your questions. Disadvantage of using that one = your question threads will get interrupted by other people, asking about & discussing *their* topics. I will create a new room for you, based off this question. You can invite members from the main chat room, to join it - keeps your topic in one place

Comment: Chat room for further discussion is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124216/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-do-masterthesis-optimization-design-a-board). **Please use this chat instead of comments.** That will allow members to be invited into *this* chat from the main chat room, and it will avoid the need to delete new comments which arrive later, and which would split the discussion into two places (chat and comments).

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - Your comment has been moved to chat. Please keep any follow-up comments in the chat, so that the whole thread continues there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the amount of work you are describing is big. But it is feasible if you split it into smaller manageable tasks.

I would suggest to take a paper and pencil and split your design into functional blocks. The goal here is to try to create smaller independent things. Then you define the interface between the blocks.

That way, when designing one of theses blocks, you only have to care about the content of the block itself and the interfaces to the other blocks. Nothing else.

For instance:
You have to design the power supply part of you board.
The interfaces are:

- Input: 12V to 24V
- Output A: ​12V at XX Amps (the XX amps requirement comes from the actuator block)
- Output B: 3V3 at YY Amps (the YY amps requirement comes from the ESP block, the LAN block,...)
- Other requirements such as stability, ripple, etc...

You don't need anything else to design your power supply. Thus now you can start designing the block.
Select the chip, do the schematics, if unsure you can even prototype it.

Then you move to the next block, the LAN part for instance.

- Input: 3v3 ( at the end of the design phase you can put here what is the works case consumption of that block for the 3v3, this is useful for the design of the power supply block)
- IO with the ESP: RMII ? SPI ? I2C? how many pins? IO voltages 3v3?

For each block you can take inspiration from the "application" page of the datasheet of the chip you are using. I said "inspiration" not dumb "copy paste" !

This depends on the schematics capture software you use, but a good practice is to put one block on one schematics page, and use "hierarchical pages" on that software. That allows you to control which signal on a schematic page goes out of that page. The goal here is too keep thing isolated unless you decide otherwise. That isolation is what makes complex things manageable and kept under control.

Once your schematics is captured it's time to check the BOM (Bill of Material). Are you sure that all the components you have put on that schematics are available ? Can you order them and get them on time ? ( I recently designed a small sound card that uses a STM32F730. I prototyped it and decided to move forward and order the part for 10 boards. Then I found out that the MCU can only be delivered in 8 months !!!! -> back to the drawing board and redesign with another MCU... a lot of time lost in the process. I should have checked the availability much sooner)

Next step is to do the layout. But to do so you first need to know the capabilities of the PCB manufacturing house. Check their website for things such as minimum track width, clearance distances, etc... And enter them into your routing software. If done correctly, the software will ensure that what you draw in your layout will be accepted by the PCB house.

Then you decide where you want to put each block on the PCB. Like: powers supply on the top left. I want the RJ45 for the lan at the bottom. etc...

Then do the routing.

Once done, use the "design rule check" function of the software to check your routing. It should check that you haven't forgot to route a net; That all the clearance complies with what the PCB house is capable to make; etc...

Then you order the parts, order the PCB, and start the software.